# How to create a sandbox with C#

Tags: sandbox

How to create a similar to the SandBox environment,That it can virtualise the registry and file table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using virtual machine software like virtual box, virtual pc, vmware etc. You would install your preferred OS on the virtual setup and create like a restore image. Then you can mess around on that virtual environment and just restore when you need to.